# How can I test for the correct rendering of specific Unicode glyphs from Haskell?

Tags: haskell, unicode

I have a Haskell package in which I would like, ideally, to use some specific Unicode glyphs, but to chose alternates if they are not available or will not be correctly rendered.

For example I would like to test whether the environment in which my code is currently running can render combining overline (U+0305) and combining low line (U+0332) in an expression such as

```
K\818\773L
```

as

```
K̲̅L
```

rather than as

```
K_ ̅L
```

or even as

```
KÌ²ÌL
```

Is there a way to do this in Haskell? For example something like

```
decorate ch = if someTestForCapabilities then ch:"\818\773" else ['[',ch,']']
```

My [current approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33015419/656912) is to seek a way to document this and just prepare the user for some odd output; but I'd prefer to detect the relevant capabilities (at runtime) and make an adequate substitution (e.g., `[K]`) when needed.

---

NOTE: For some reason, the first version may not render consistently correctly here. It appears to in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33015419/656912), and in the editor, though.

Comment: "use some specific Unicode glyphs". If you output to a specific rendering system such as WinAPI or X11 or freetype that has a notion of fonts and glyphs, you need to consult the documentation for that system. If you output some Unicode characters to a stream, just output some Unicode characters to a stream. Your stream can be a disk file, or a socket connected to a remote machine, or whatever. It is meaningless to ask if a certain glyph is available in a stream. There are no glyphs, only bytes.

Comment: The best thing I can think of is to actually render it and do some computer vision. The pango library has [`pango_font_get_coverage`](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Fonts.html#pango-font-get-coverage), and you could add a binding to the [pango](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pango) package without too much trouble, but that gets coverage at the codepoint level and I'm not too sure about the interaction between combining codepoint coverage and glyph rendering.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Yes, I expect this is tougher than I would have hoped. And I bet even if I could work something out to check or the presence of whatever capability I can check for in a specific kind of environment, the check would be different for each — and even then, I couldn't be sure what it would actually *look* like. And the proof is right here: I get the correct result in one question (for me in my browser, anyway) and not for another, using the same input! I'm probably better off just figure out lacer way to [warn users](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33015419/656912).

Comment: It might be easiest for everyone involved if you just provided a way for the user to configure which alternate is used in a config file or via command line arguments.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: Yes. that may be the way to go.

Comment: I suppose you could always render it yourself as a SVG.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs: I'd except something like "that's not possible or at least very difficult" and "better in any case would be to provide an option to select an alternate" as an answer.